# Why whenever I refresh my random forest regressor. The MSE and MAE change? why does it vary and depend on what?

Tags: python, machine-learning, output, random-forest

I am using jupyter notebook so I can refresh the chunk to fit/predict/evaluate as often as I can. Everytime I refresh, the MSE/MAE/RMSE returns a different value even though the training data is not shuffled. Why is that so?

I have tried looking the problem up but that seems of no help so I wonder if it is because of my code or my lack of understanding

I refresh this chunk often

```
rf1 = SklearnExtra(clf = RandomForestRegressor(), seed = Seed, params = tune)
rf1.fit(x_train, y_train)
evaluate(rf1, x_test, y_test)
print('Test MAPE '+ str(mean_absolute_percentage_error(rf1, y_test, x_test)))
```

```
def evaluate(model, test_features, test_labels):
    predictions = model.predict(test_features)
    errors = metrics.mean_absolute_error(test_labels, predictions)
    MSerrors = metrics.mean_squared_error(test_labels, predictions)
    RMSE = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(test_labels, predictions))
    RMSLE = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power(np.log1p(predictions) - np.log1p(test_labels), 2)))
    print('Model Perfomance')
    print('MAE Error: {:0.4f} degrees. '.format(errors))
    print('Average MSE Error: {:0.4f} degrees. '.format(MSerrors))
    print('Average RMS Error: {:0.4f} degrees. '.format(RMSE))
    print('Average RMSLE Error: {:0.4f} degrees. '.format(RMSLE))
    return 'end of test'
```

```
class SklearnExtra(object):
    def __init__(self, clf, seed = 0, params = None):
        params['random_state'] = seed
        self.clf = clf

    def train(self, x, y):
        self.clf.fit(x, y)

    def predict(self, x):
        return self.clf.predict(x)

    def fit(self, x, y):
        return self.clf.fit(x,y)

    def feature_importances(self, x, y):
        clf2 = self.clf.fit(x,y)
        return (clf2.feature_importances_)

    def name(self):
        return str(self.clf)
```

```
Test Data
Model Perfomance
MAE Error: 26.3329 degrees. 
Average MSE Error: 1950.4288 degrees. 
Average RMS Error: 44.1637 degrees. 
Average RMSLE Error: 0.3016 degrees. 
Test MAPE 24.11994617834992

#next refresh
Test Data
Model Perfomance
MAE Error: 29.7638 degrees. 
Average MSE Error: 2479.5202 degrees. 
Average RMS Error: 49.7948 degrees. 
Average RMSLE Error: 0.3129 degrees. 
Test MAPE 25.520876708239378
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every tree is built on a random part of the data (bootstrap) and/or on a subsample of all features, so the model is different every time. It's a *random* forest ;-)

You can turn of the bootstap sampling with `RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=False)`, but you will still get slightly different results every time from the feature sampling.

But you can set the `randon_state` parameter to a fix value, if you like to get the same result every time, e.g. `RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)`. :-)

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354336/what-happens-when-bootstrapping-isnt-used-in-sklearn-randomforestclassifier) is a nice explanation from Sycorax on CrossValidated.